# Razor Pages ASP.Net Core 2.0 Routing - Is possible to have a parameters in the middle of a URL?

Tags: asp.net, razor, url-routing, asp.net-core-2.0

Is it possible to have a parameter in the middle of the URL for a Razor Page?

Example:

- http://website/products <--- Shows a list of products
- http://website/products/{productName} - Product Page
- http://website/products/{productName}/Page1
- http://website/products/{productName}/Page2
- http://website/products/{productName}/ListOfAccessories
- http://website/products/{productName}/ListOfAccessories/Details

File Structure:

- /products/Index <--- Shows the list of products
- /Products/Product/Index <-- Product Page
- /Products/Product/Page1
- /Products/Product/Page2
- /Products/Product/ListOfAccessories/Index
- /Products/Product/ListOfAccessories/Details

I can create the route for the products list, but can't figure out the parameter in the middle of the URL using **options.Conventions.AddPageRoute**

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can add a convention and use parameters inside the same way as in controller routes.

```
 options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products", "products/{id}/details")
 options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products", "products/{id}/listofaccesories")
```

or in a more general way

```
 options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Products", "products/{id}/{handler}")
```

The **{handler}** parameter will be used by the razor pages engine to find a method mapping this route.
This two configurations will route the url **/products/20120/details** to the `ProductsModel` page, taking the `20120` as the `id` argument and selecting the `Details` handler inside the `ProductsModel`.

```
public ProductsModel : PageModel
{
    ...

   public Task OnGetDetails(int id)
    {
    ...
    }

    public Task OnGetListOfAccessories(int id)
    {
       ...
    }

   ...
}
```